# Ruby on rails: how to set up string translation inline (witnout changing config/locales/*.yml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, locale, redmine

I'm using the [Custom Workflows](https://www.redmine.org/plugins/custom-workflows) plugin for Redmine. It gives an ability to write code for e.g. before_save hook in admin page in runtime. Assume that I raise the exception on it:

```
  raise WorkflowError, "Warning: your note is too long."
```

In classical coding I should write

```
  raise WorkflowError, t(:warning_note_too_long)
```

and modify e.g. en locale:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  warning_note_too_long: "Warning: your note is too long."
```

but in this case it is unacceptable because the sense of writing code in the admin page is lost (I should also modify sources and deploy them).

How can I translate the message to several languages inline? I want something like that:

```
  config.locales.en.warning_note_too_long = "Warning: your note is too long."
  config.locales.ru.warning_note_too_long ="Предупреждение: Ваш комментарий слишком длинный."
  raise WorkflowError, t(:warning_note_too_long)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

```
message = case I18n.locale
          when 'ru'
            "Предупреждение: Ваш комментарий слишком длинный."
          else # keeping 'en' as default in case there is some unexpected locale
            "Warning: your note is too long."
          end
raise WorkflowError, message
```

Comment: work fine with this modification:
message = case I18n.locale.to_s